# How to interpret "ln" cmd output (WinDbg)?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, memory-address

I'm trying to find where the app faulted using 'ln' cmd which is normally supposed to help with that. 47a6c6 is the fault offset reported in the logs. I'm just wondering what I have to do with that info about before/after symbol in the code.

```
0:000> lm
...
0000000000400000 0000000000a5c000   llm   ...
...

0:000> ln 00400000+47a6c6
```

And I got this:

```
(000000000078b4a0)   llm!videoCodec+0xef226   |  (00000000009430a0)   llm!videoDevice
```

Could you please explain what it means exactly? And how am I supposed to work with that?

**Solution:**

Looks like 47a6c6 was already the final faulted address:

*(04-01-23 15:39:27.638) Exception c0000005 in Ctrl(0) at 47a6c6*.

start+faulted offset=47a6c6
So, I found the function where the app failed:

0:000>ln 47a6c6

*c:*****\llmgroup\llm\digimot.cpp(**5705**)+0x3 (0000000000478ed0)   llm!**CtrlThread+0x17f6**   |  (0000000000480450) llm!CDigiMotion::MemberThreadOpen*

0:000>ln llm!CtrlThread+0x17f

*c:*****\llmgroup\llm\digimot.cpp(**5382**)+0x12 (00000000`00478ed0) llm!**CtrlThread+0x17f**   |  (0000000000480450) llm!CDigiMotion::MemberThreadOpen*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual: [`ln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ln--list-nearest-symbols-).

1. The nearest symbol (function) before the address `00400000+47a6c6` is `videoCodec` in the module `llm` (perhaps llm.dll). The symbol address is `0078b4a0`, the requested address is the offset `0xef226` after the symbol `videoCodec`.
2. The nearest symbol (function) after the address `00400000+47a6c6` is `videoDevice` in the module `llm`. The symbol address is `009430a0`.
3. The module `llm` is loaded at the addresses `00400000` to `00a5c000`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I'm wondering how to work with this info in the code. I mean I tried to load source file path to try determining the exact place (line in source file). But it keeps showing the nearest symbol before and after the given address. Not sure how to apply this info.

Comment: @kirillshvedov: there's too little information in your question. We don't even know what you are trying to achieve. Therefore it's also hard to explain how you might benefit from `ln`. Maybe you do, maybe you don't, maybe `ln` is totally the wrong command. Typically you can use `k` to get the exactly place where your app faults. I have no idea why you try to use `ln` in the first place. From the abbreviated output, I have no clue why you chose `ln 00400000+47a6c6` over `ln 400000+a5c000`. `47a6c6` comes like a magic number with no explanation.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I'm trying to find where the app faulted obviously (as said in the case description) using 'ln' cmd which is normally supposed to help with that. I don't understand what you mean by 'ln 400000+a5c000'. Don't you understand what this line means: '0000000000400000 0000000000a5c000   llm ...'?  47a6c6 is not a magic number but the fault offset reported in the logs. I'm just wondering what I have to do with that info about before/after symbol in the code. I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: Looks like 47a6c6 was already the final faulted address. **(04-01-23 15:39:27.638) Exception c0000005 in Ctrl(0) at 47a6c6**. start+faulted offset=47a6c6. So, I found the function where the app failed. **c:\*****\llmgroup\llm\digimot.cpp(5705)+0x3
(00000000`00478ed0)   llm!CtrlThread+0x17f6   |  (00000000`00480450)   llm!CDigiMotion::MemberThreadOpen** Thanks @273K

Comment: @kirillshvedov: all the info you've given in the comments now should be part of the question. Someone (like @273K or me) could have told you that you don't need to `400000+47a6c6` if e.g. the exception information were part of the original post.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thanks for the advice. I'll try to make up a question based on your recommendations next time. But the problem was that the address should normally be the faulted offset as it always is in most of codes. But this time it turned out that it is already the resulted memory address in the module (start+offset).